# Geb groovy simple setup, getting NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: groovy, webdriver, geb, groovy-eclipse

I'm learning Geb (and Groovy) coming from a Java background, and I feel like I understand how Geb works, but I'm failing to even get the simplest configuration working.
Basically, I'm getting the following error:

> Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: geb/error/GebException
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: geb/error/GebException
>         at DriveIt.run(DriveIt.groovy:15)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: geb.error.GebException
>         ... 1 more

My class is very simple:

```
    import groovy.grape.Grape  
    // I have these out of desperation  
    Grape.grab(group:"org.gebish", module:"geb-core", version:"0.9.3")
    Grape.grab(group:"org.seleniumhq.selenium", module:"selenium-firefox-driver", version:"2.41.0")
    Grape.grab(group:"org.seleniumhq.selenium", module:"selenium-support", version:"2.41.0")

// basic imports here
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
    import geb.Browser;

    Browser.drive {
        go "http://www.google.com"   
    }
```

With this simple code i get an error on the "Browser.drive" line.

This is what my GebConfig.groovy file looks like:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

driver = {
    def driver = new ChromeDriver()
    driver
}

baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/'
reportsDir = 'target/geb-reports'
```

And one more note, I'm using Eclipse, I do have the geb-code jar correctly imported in the classpath as well.
I don't seem to be doing anything incorrectly, but for the life of me, I can't figure out why I get an error saying "Browser" not recognized.

Any help??? please!!

Answer (score 0):

You can download needed package via command line by using command `grape install org.gebish geb-core 0.9.3`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll go home and try this out. So, you're saying that importing and using grape is not enough?

Comment: Hello again, that didn't do anything. Not really sure what the 'grape' command is. i don't think there's any other way to install geb-core through terminal either. btw, i am on a unix environment (mac os).

Comment: Well, it can't find Browser class. Did you check if you have geb-core-0.9.3 under `%user%/.groovy\grapes\org.gebish\geb-core\jars` directory?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `@Grab` as an annotation for it work. See: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape.

Also, you might consider looking at [this example project](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle) to learn how to use Geb with Gradle - using a build system to resolve your dependencies might be the most sensible thing in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, none of the solutions really worked. I instead recreated an new Groovy project using Maven, which automatically downloaded all the dependencies. I then added  the geb-core 0.9.3 dependency, which finally fixed it.